# Spotlight can find deleted iCloud-synced page file, but unable to open it

Tags: macos, spotlight

I encountered a bug on macOS where I created and saved a Pages file, which was then synced to iCloud. However, when I directly deleted the file and emptied the trash, I noticed that Spotlight can still search for the deleted file. Reindexing the spotlight does not seem to work